PyQt6 - QListView - Drag and Drop Bug?
I currently having the issue that my QListView causes really strange behavior:

I apply a Model
I set dragDropMode to InternalMove

I can drag and drop, but when I drop the item on the other instead of above/below/between, the item just disappears. Is this a bug? I found some info regarding this, but nothing really helped. A work around for me is currently to implement a custom QListView and determine if the drop was ON an item, in that case don't route the event to the parent class... t:
    model = CustomListModel(["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"])
    self.list_view.setModel(model)
    self.list_view.setDragDropMode(QListView.DragDropMode.InternalMove)

I tried downgrading to earlier pyqt5 versions as well as upgrading to pyqt6. No change
Any help is highly appreciated

By default, views call the model's dropMimeData(), and the default behavior of QAbstractListModel is to replace the item. If you want to prevent drop on items, just override flags() on the model and always remove Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled from the resulting flags before returning. Eg: return super().flags() & ~Qt.ItemFlags.ItemIsDropEnabled

Also note that you're using QListView, ListView is another thing. While similar in concepts, they're used in different contexts (Qt Widgets and QML) and it's important to use the proper naming, otherwise people may not find your question easily, or may get it in the middle of other results and as an irrelevant one.

Thank you @musicamante,
i tried, but sadly it does not solve the issue that I want (just) internal movement.

Please don't add answers to the question. Undo the edit and provide the solution in the related answer field by clicking the "Answer your question" button. Also, if you specified that you were using a QStandardItemModel, the solution would've been even simpler, since QStandardItem has a dedicated function: setDropEnabled().

Thank you for the info, hope it is ok as it is now?

Thank you so much musicamante, I tried for hours yesterday and it was so frustrating. The solution is just so simple. Check if we have a valid index (=drop on an item), then don't allow, otherwise allow. Great!
class CustomListModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, elements: List[str] = None):
        super().__init__()

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            # Remove the Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled flag to prevent dropping on an item
            return super().flags(index) & ~Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return super().flags(index) | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled

edit
Alternative solution also works, thank you! In CustomListModel(QStandardItemModel):
def add_element(self, element: str, sort: bool = False):
    item = QStandardItem(element)
    item.setEditable(False)
    item.setDropEnabled(False)
    self.appendRow(item)

Old answer
The suggestion from musicamante was to overwrite the default behaviour that dropping on items overwrites them by setting Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled to false:
class CustomListModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, elements: List[str] = None):
        super().__init__()

    def flags(self, index):
        return super().flags(index) & ~Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled

While this prevents the drop on items and the subsequent overwriting, it also prevents internal movement if items. So it does not solve my problem.
